# Linq query on list and projecting into object that can be sent to a view and rendered in a dropbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, drop-down-menu

I am building an asp.net mvc web application.
I have the following set up so that my application can ask a person questions with multi-choice answers.

```
public class newPerson
{
   public List <Question> Question {get; set;}
   // and other properties
}

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId{get; set;}
    public string QuestionText {get; set;}
    public List<Answer> Answers {get; set;} //list of multi-choice answers
}

public class Answer
{
     public int Answerid{get; set;}
     public string AnswerText {get; set;}
     public Question Question{get; set;}    
}
```

In my controller I have an instance of newPerson called person which is populated with questions and answers.  I also have a question id called questId.   I would like to write a linq query which does the following:

query person and select the answers that are associated with questId.  Project the Answerids and AnswerTexts into an object that I can send to my view and render in a dropbox.

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have a "question"-object inside your "Answer"-Class ??? Doesn't that make it unnecessary complicated?

Comment: this is straight-forward using something like `Question.Where(q => q.QuestionId == questId).SelectMany(q => Answers).Select(a => ...)` - what have you tried?

Comment: I agree it does look a bit daft.  Its there because of other queries I've done in the application.  I'm using NHibernate and it seems that having it there is the only way to achieve cross table queries.  I will take another look and make sure its necessary.  Thanks.

Comment: Carsten, I had tried to solve the problem using various different ways using query syntax but none worked.  Your method however works beautifully.  Thank you very much!  Obviously in my case it is person.Question.Where...